# Real and Imaginary Parts of $z^z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Apologies if I don't write this question clearly; this is my first time using the site and I'm not sure if I'm following all the proper protocols here.

I'm working through Ahlfor's Complex Analysis, and I'm stumped by the question on page 47 that asks you to find the real and imaginary parts of $z^z$. What kind of strategy could I use to start in on this problem?

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: First of, how do you define $z^z$ ?

Comment: $z=x+iy$ or $z=re^{i\theta}$

Comment: No, not $z$, but $z^z$. For example, how do you define $i^i$?

Comment: $i^{i}=e^{ilog{i}}$ is how I would think of that I think?

Comment: Can you get the real and imaginary parts of $e^z$? If so you are almost finished ...

Comment: $e^{x+iy}=e^{x}(\cos{y}) +e^{x}(i\sin{xy})$, so the real part is $x\cos{y}$ and the imaginary part is $e^{x}(\sin{xy})i$, right?

Comment: It should be $sin(y)$ but other than that its right. Now apply all that to $z^z$ and you should be able to do it :)

Comment: So, is this right? with $r, \theta$ defined in terms of $x$ and $y$, $z^z=(re^i\theta)^z=r^z(e^{iz}^{z})=r^{z}e^{i\thetax-\thetay}=r^z(e^{-\thetay}cos(\thetax)+r^ze^{-\thetay}sin{\thetax}i$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, we define $z = a+ib $, $z = re^{i\theta}$, with $r$ ,$\theta$  its the modulus and argument respectively.

\begin{align*}
z^z &= e^{z\log{z}} \\
  \end{align*}

We have :
  \begin{align*}
\log{z} &= \log{(re^{i\theta})} \\
&= \log{r} + i\theta \\
  \end{align*}
Then 
  \begin{align*}
z^z &= e^{z\log{z}} \\
 &= e^{(a+ib)(\log{r} + i\theta)} \\
 &= e^{(a\log{r} -b\theta) + i (a\theta+b\log{r})} \\
&= e^{a\log{r} -b\theta} \big(\cos(a\theta+b\log{r}) + i \sin(a\theta+b\log{r}) \big) \\
  \end{align*}